# How to make python apscheduler trigger a function inside a class instance

Tags: apscheduler

I have a class which has BaseScheduler as an attribute, nothing fancy, no frameworks etc.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, ...):
       ...
       self.Scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
       ...
```

Later on I define methods that a) schedule jobs based on a schedule definition passed as kwargs, and b) handle the jobs when they are triggered:

```
def _schedule_Events(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    try:
        Schedule_Def = kwargs.copy()
        Schedule_Def['func'] = self._handle_scheduled_Event
        job = self.Scheduler.add_job(**Schedule_Def)
        self.Scheduled_Events.append(job)
    except Exception as e:
        self.Logger.exception('%s: exception in schedule_Events, details: %s' %(self.Name, e))    

def _handle_scheduled_Event(self, Event_Action):
    """ Callback function for scheduled jobs """
    try:
        .... do stuff ....
```

However, adding jobs with _schedule_Events fails with:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 381, in check_callable_args
    ', '.join(unsatisfied_args))
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: Event_Action
```

The reason is apparently that the 'func' argument must be globally callable, ie. not within a class instance scope. I also don't see how using a 'textual reference' as described in the documentation will help.

If I replace the 'func' callable with a function defined at the module level then it works, but I need to make it call a method within my instance object.  Any ideas how to make this work ?  Custom trigger ? Wrapping APS Scheduler inside another class and pass the callback ? Other ideas ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you calling `_schedule_Events()`?

Comment: Also, not related but I suggest you adopt a better naming scheme. The PEP 8 standard dictates that only classes should be named in CamelCase, variables and functions in lower_case.

Comment: _schedule_Events() is called from the class event loop start() method, and also by the class' event handler, e.g. when an event named reload_Events fires.

Re the CamelCase - thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer this style as it separates verbs from nouns and thus makes it easier for me to read - this is based on German grammar.

Comment: You really have to show more code, or construct a stand-alone script to demonstrate the issue. I cannot help you with this much obfuscation in the way.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will construct a stand-alone script but it will take me a little while.  Keep you posted and thanks for your patience.

Comment: I have refactored/rewritten my code and now it works fine.